# Is POCO the right choice when working with entity framework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, poco

I've been reading about POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) for a while but still can't find the real added value of using it instead of using the auto generated partial classes of the entity framework?
One more thing is it best to use my entity framework directly from the presentation layer or creating a BLL will be better?

Comment: POCOs are perhaps debatable, but I find them to be nice and 'clean' and more portable as compared to Entity Objects. What I *don't* find debatable, though, is that data access code should never be in the presentation layer. But both of those are my *opinions*...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main benefit of a POCO is that you can pass it to a class, library or assembly that doesn't need to know anything about Entity Framework to do its job.

Remember the Single Responsibility Principle - your DAL should know about EF, but your Domain should not, and neither should your presentation layer, because EF deals with data access and those layers do not.  Passing EF generated class objects up to those layers generally means you need to make those layers aware of EF, breaking the SRP and making it harder to unit test those layers in isolation.

In response to Ali's further query in the comments below, here is an expanded explanation.

In more complex applications, you will want to split the logic up into separate concerns - data access, business logic, presentation (and perhaps a lot more).

As entity framework deals with data access, it resides in the data access layer - here, you will see little difference between POCOs and EF generated classes.  This is fine, because this layer already knows about Entity Framework.

However, you may want to pass data up to the business logic layer - if you do this with EF generated classes, then your business logic layer must also know about Entity Framework because the EF classes rely on a lot of things EF provides specially.  What this does is remove the isolation that your business logic layer should have - you need this isolation so you can unit test it correctly by injecting known data into the class from a fake data access layer, which is incredibly hard to do if you let the business logic layer know about EF.

With unit testing, you should be testing the layers functionality, not the functionality of third party libraries - but with EF you end up testing a lot of EF's functionality, or your own functionality which relies very heavily on that of EF's.  This isn't good, and it can mask errors or issues.

Removing the business logics dependency on EF generated classes also allows you to move the layer to as remote a location as you like from the data access layer - you can even stick it behind a web service and it would be completely happy.  But you can only do this with POCOs, you cannot do this with EF generated classes.

POCO's really come into their own in large, complex multi layered applications - if you aren't layering your app, then you won't see a whole load of benefits imho.

All of this is my opinion, and I'm just a coder with experience - I'm not a coding rockstar, so some other commenters may like to further expand my answers...

Comment: Exactly. The other answers seem to be making a two-way link between Code First and POCOs, but the link really only goes one-way. POCOs are a benefit on their own.

Comment: Yup, a major project Im developing right now is database first, but I use one of the POCO templates to generate the POCOS and datacontexts - no EF bound objects in sight :)

Comment: In EF 4.1 I used the auto generate code for poco which is slightly easy to use, but didn't notice the real difference between it and the auto generated entities, can anyone help a bit here plz?

Comment: @Ali - I've added some extra detail.

Answer (score 1):

The real benefits with POCO is that you can use code first and EF Migrations. If you are not going to use code first you can use the designer generated classes.

If you have a large application you should create a separate BLL, but if your application is very small you can probably go directly with the EF classes in the presentation layer.

Comment: my application is a news portal not very small but not huge as well, can you please give more details about "code first" issue

Comment: @AliIssa I wouldn't worry about Code First; you would already know if you were using it. Code First basically starts from POCOs, but you don't at all need to be using Code First to use POCOs. I would recommend you use POCOs if at all *possible*, because they are easier to interoperate with. Entities are simply (though slightly) more complex to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Using POCO classes in an ORM allows you to create tests for that code in an easier manner. It also allows you to have a layer of abstraction between your model objects (the POCO classes) and the data access code so if you need to you can swap the data access code (EF for NHibernate, for instance).

I've worked with the POCO model in the past and I can tell you that it's useful for big enterprise projects and large teams of developers where changes to the model happen often and where the monolithic file model used by default by EF does not scale well. The benefits on small projects or in rapid application development are hard to see.

**TLDR version:** If you're asking yourself what the benefits of POCO and code first are, you probably won't gain anything from using them.

Comment: I find POCOs easier to work with in general (though they do take an extra step or two to set up at the very start of a project). It's just generally easier to pass around POCOs than Entities.